# Where the lifecycle phase number comes from in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-framework-beans

When stopping a SpringBoot application, INFO log messages like the one below can be witnessed.
Where that phase number comes from?

```
o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That value is set to 2147483647 by default by Spring Framework in [org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.java) interface

```
int DEFAULT_PHASE = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Verification:

```
jshell> Integer.MAX_VALUE
$1 ==> 2147483647
```